# How do I output the page ID instead of the page URL from a 2sxc Content field?

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a 2sxc Content module that uses C# Razor for the template. In my content type, I have a field called "Link" and the type is a Link that's configured to only allow the user to select a DNN page from the dropdown.

When the user chooses a page from the dropdown, it puts something like "page:38" where "38" is the DNN tab ID.

In my C# razor template, I put @Content.Link and it will output something like domain.com/our-services. (our-services being the URL associated with the tab ID 38).

I'm building something where I want to actually output just the page ID. So instead of @Content.Link outputting /our-services, I want it to output the page ID "38".

How can I do this in c# razor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Let's say your field is called `Link` then as of now you're doing `@Content.Link`. This will auto-resolve links.

If you don't want to auto-resolve, you must use `Content.Get("Link", convertLinks: false)` to get the original string, and then extract the ID with substring or regex.

See also https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Data.DynamicEntity.html#ToSic_Sxc_Data_DynamicEntity_Get_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_

Comment: For the purpose of simplifying, I used an example where the Link field is just a regular field. In my cases, I'm actually using sub-entities so I'm looping through a list of links within my content module. I tried the code you suggested, swapping out Content with the variable used in my sub-entity loop "pathwayItem" but I keep getting the error "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" 

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

@iJungleBoy, I tried to get this to work using your answer above and was not able to. No matter how I use .Get(), I get a null reference exception. I am on 2sxc 11.3; when was .Get() added? and was it maybe fixed later than 11.3?

Here is what I am playing with, maybe you can spot my error(s)? In the code below, .LinkedPages is an Entity field that allows multiple of another Content-Type that has a Hyperlink field type named "Page"; you can see the results of the first 3 below.

Code:

```
  foreach(var pg in pub.LinkedPages)
  {
    <p>Debug: <br>
    <span>    .Page: @pg.Page<br></span>
    <span>Get(name): @pg.Get("Page")<br></span>
    <span>  GetType: @pg.GetType()<br></span>
    <span>Get(name, convertLinks): AsEntity(pg).Get(name: "Page", language: "en", convertLinks: false)</span>
    </p>
  }
```

Result w/o error:

```
Debug:
1.         .Page: https://staging.com/products/fiber-fed-pulsed-plasma-thruster-fppt
2.  .Get("Page"): https://staging.com/products/fiber-fed-pulsed-plasma-thruster-fppt
3.    .GetType(): ToSic.Sxc.Data.DynamicEntity
```

I have also tried many variations like:

- @AsEntity(pg).Get(...)
- @((pg as object).Get(name: "Page", ...
- @pg.Get(name: "Page", dontRelyOnParameterOrder: Constants.RandomProtectionParameter, language: "en-us", convertLinks: false)

and quite a few others but always get the null reference error even when it seems correct per the docs. Thoughts?

For this variation/test
`@pg.Get(name: "Page", convertLinks: false)`

Here is the full error:

```
Error: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , Boolean ) at 
System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) at 
CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , Boolean ) at 
System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) at 
ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_Content__CUA__PubPaper__List__basic_cshtml.Execute() 
in c:\{siteroot}\Portals\0\2sxc\Content\_CUA\_PubPaper__List--basic.cshtml:line 98 at 
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at 
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at 
ToSic.Sxc.Engines.RazorEngine.Render(TextWriter writer) 
in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Razor\Engines\Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 67 at 
ToSic.Sxc.Engines.RazorEngine.RenderTemplate() 
in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Razor\Engines\Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 77 at 
ToSic.Sxc.Engines.EngineBase.Render() 
in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line 150 at 
ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.BlockBuilder.Render() 
in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\BlockBuilder_Render.cs:line 57
```

Comment: I believe Get, especially with the overload which has `convertLinks: false` is fairly new. There was also a command (I believe AsEntity(...).GetBestValue(name, ...)` but that's being deprecated, so it's not listed in the docs any more. I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: You are correct, upgrading did the trick. Frustrating to lose so much time experimenting and reporting, but happy its behind me.

`@pg.Get(name: "Page", convertLinks: false)`
 
Now returns as expected: `page:93`